# Java byte[] to String and UTF-8

Tags: java, string, utf-8, encryption

I am implementing a [Cipher Block Chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation) for school work and the question asks for a method taking `String` and returning another `String`. At first, I thought it was odd and that `byte[]` variables would be much more adequate, but implemented a method still. Basically, here's the code :

```
static public String encode(String message) {
   byte[] dataMessage = message.getBytes();
   ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

   byte last = (byte) (Math.random() * 256);
   byte cur;
   out.write(last);

   for (byte b : data) {
      cur = (byte) (b^last);
      System.out.println("Encode '" + (char) b + "' = " + b + "^" + last + " > " + cur );
      out.write( cur );
      last = cur;
   }

   System.out.println("**ENCODED BYTES = " + Arrays.toString(out.toByteArray()));
   System.out.println("**ENCODED STR   = " + Arrays.toString(out.toString().getBytes()));

   return out.toString();
}
```

The `decode` method works similarly. Some times, the method will spit results like

```
Encode 'H' = 72^109 > 37
Encode 'e' = 101^37 > 64
Encode 'l' = 108^64 > 44
Encode 'l' = 108^44 > 64
Encode 'o' = 111^64 > 47
**ENCODED BYTES = [109, 37, 64, 44, 64, 47]
**ENCODED STR   = [109, 37, 64, 44, 64, 47]
```

But sometimes will also spit things like

```
Encode 'H' = 72^-63 > -119
Encode 'e' = 101^-119 > -20
Encode 'l' = 108^-20 > -128
Encode 'l' = 108^-128 > -20
Encode 'o' = 111^-20 > -125
**ENCODED BYTES = [-63, -119, -20, -128, -20, -125]
**ENCODED STR   = [-17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67]
```

I presume that this has something to do with UTF-8 (the system's default encoding), but I'm not familiar enough to figure out *exactly* why such a string would be returned with the given bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't take an arbitrary sequence of bytes and assume it's a valid UTF-8 encoded string. So, I suspect that the `toString` method, as [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toString%28%29), *replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character sequences with the default replacement string for the platform's default character set*.

You should thus not transform purely binary data into a String like this. Use some encoding like Hex or Base64 to transform your bytes to a printable string, and vice-versa.

Apache commons-codec has a Base64 utility class.

Comment: Yes, it replaces every character sequence (the four of them, UTF-8 has a self-synchronizing property that makes it skip to what looks like the start of the next multibyte character) is replaced by U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER (in UTF8: 0xef 0xbf 0xbd).

Comment: Yes, this is what I think happens (about the replacement character). And I will use a Base64 implementation then.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
out.toString().getBytes()
```

is not doing what you expect. It takes the encrypted bytes and interprets those bytes as if they are an UTF-8 encoded string. Then it converts the characters in that string back to bytes.

You can't just take arbitrary bytes (in this case, the encrypted data) and then handle it as if it is UTF-8 encoded text.